# 'Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation' when trying to support cross browser prefixes in clojurescript

Tags: javascript, clojurescript

`getUserMedia` has a number of prefixes that are still necessary in many browsers. I am attempting to hide the use of these prefixes by putting all the prefixes in `getUserMedia`.

```
(def getUserMedia
  (or js/navigator.getUserMedia
      js/navigator.webkitGetUserMedia
      js/navigator.mozGetUserMedia
      js/navigator.msGetUserMedia))

(defn start-fx [app]
  (if getUserMedia
    (getUserMedia 
     ;; WORKS IF I REPLACE THE ABOVE getUserMedia WITH
     ;; js/navigator.webkitGetUserMedia USING CHROME BROWSER
     #js {:video true :audio true}
     #(om/update! app :record-src (.createObjectURL js/window.URL %))
     #(throw %))
    (js/alert "This browser does not support video recording!")))
```

When I then attempt to call this from `start-fx`, I get a `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation` at the calling of `getUserMedia`. What should I do to allow my code to be cross browser compatible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getUserMedia` has to be bound to the `navigator` object. The equivalent JavaScript would be this:

```
var getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                   navigator.mozGetUserMedia || msGetUserMedia;
if (getUserMedia) {
  getUserMedia = getUserMedia.bind(navigator);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to have an answer, I am posting my fix for the problem. Ugh, surely there must be a better solution available?

```
(def getUserMedia
  (or js/navigator.getUserMedia
      js/navigator.webkitGetUserMedia
      js/navigator.mozGetUserMedia
      js/navigator.msGetUserMedia))

(defn start-fx [app]
  (if getUserMedia
    (let [[c s f] [#js {:video true :audio true}
                   #(om/update! app 
                               :record-src 
                               (.createObjectURL js/window.URL %))
                   #(throw %)]]
      (getUserMedia c s f))
    (js/alert "This browser does not support video recording!")))
```

Comment: I think you can replace the entire `cond` with `(getUserMedia c s f)`

Comment: I think I agree. I will make the change.